# Installing Times New Roman font

Tags: fonts

How can I install the Times New Roman font?  [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rg3GWXCUP0) illustrates what I want to do, but I do not have the same options - I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

I have also tried running the following from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This is the message I receive:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The above did not work for me. Fortunately, http://askubuntu.com/questions/210680/installing-times-new-roman-font worked fine.

Comment: @burnsmicro Your comments links to this qestion... :/

Answer (score 56):

Your best bet may be the `--reinstall` option.

Force a reinstallation with:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

which will force the preinst and postinst scipts that actually install the fonts to be re-run.

Comment: This worked on my Ubuntu 12.04. I must remove and reinstall that package and reconfigure it. Now Times New Roman can be added into my Libreoffice. It works.

Comment: After running `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` the directory `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/` is empty. Where to look for the `.ttf` files?

Answer (score 25):

#### Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I didn't find `msttcorefonts`  in the apt pool, so I installed only `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. It works for me

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Since `msttcorefonts` is not in any current release (including 14.04), I just removed it from the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 16.04**

**Single Font Install**

If you already own a copy of the **Times New Roman Font** (and any other fonts you want to install) and have it on your local Download directory (unzipped) and ready to install, then I have a simple solution that does not require the `apt-get`.... command line or internet connection. It is a simple off-line graphical solution.

**Warning! You do have to use your wrist, finger, and mouse! But not the Terminal :-)**

Also! You have to do this manually for each font you want to install, so it could take a little time if you want a bunch of fonts junking up your system. But you did indicate **you wanted one Specific Font.... Times New Roman**. (This might work on other versions of Ubuntu as well)

Assuming the font is in your download directory.....

1. Open the Ubuntu file manager and go to the unzipped **Times.ttf** file in your download directory and
   double-click the file.
2. The Font Viewer window will open and display
   the various sizes of example font texts. eg...***The quick brown fox
   ..... whatever.......***
3. Look at the top right corner of the Font Viewer screen and you will
   see a button that says Install.
4. Click it and you are done!

When I did this, no reboot was required, with the exception of closing whatever app you were currently running like *LibreOffice Writer*. Just close and re-open Libre.

If you dont have a local copy on your machine, any WindowZ machine should have it available.
Open the file manager and go to windows, then the Fonts sub-folder/directory. Its down there somewhere listd as:

- times.ttf- normal
- **timesbd.ttf-bold**
- ***timesbi.ttf- bold italic***
- *timesi.ttf - italic*

If it's considered stealing from Bill G/MS "I dunno", but that is your call.

By the way, per the synaptic install information notes,

***ttf-mscorefonts*** install more than just the Times New Roman fonts, and I believe you still have to download them.

Comment: What a long answer just to say "If you already have the TTF, you can just double click it to open in Font Viewer and click 'install' in the top right"