# Times New Roman font missing in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, fonts

There is no Times New Roman Font present in LibreOffice Writer. I looked upon the question [Installing Times New Roman font](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210680/installing-times-new-roman-font). But I have the fonts installed on my system already, but is it not showing
up on Libreoffice Writer?

**My system specs**

```
$ libreoffice --version
LibreOffice 5.1.2.2 10m0(Build:2)
```

Comment: Try this. Go to your Software manager and search for `ttf-mscore`.Reboot your PC or restart Libreoffice

Comment: @NiteshSharma Will try it and let you know

Answer (score 9):

Probably something happened during the installation of the fonts, and the package appears installed, although the fonts themselves were not. Simply purge the package and re-install it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

A screen will appear, where you will have to accept the license agreement. Then the fonts will be downloaded and installed one by one.

Comment: (TAB+ ENTER) :to agree to the EULA!!  source - https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I was trying to install ttf_mscorefonts_installer from synaptic manager,but mine was not working. But i downloaded latest version of ubuntu16.04.2 desktop version and tried to install it.Now it is working for me.I will recommend you to install synaptic manager and install from it.

Comment: I was getting popup notification windows every time Ubuntu started that ttf-mscorefonts-installer was missing fonts after I installed 16.04, and then after 2-3 months the missing font notifications disappeared by themselves, *maybe because of a software update?*.

Answer (score -1):

I always install the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` [described here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) via Synaptic Package manager, or via terminal run these commands:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

and the fonts (Andale Mono, Arial Black, Arial (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic), Comic Sans MS (Bold), Courier New (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic), Georgia (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic), Impact, **Times New Roman (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)**, Trebuchet (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic), Verdana (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic), Webdings) are automatically available to use in LibreOffice.

Comment: The question which I mentioned states this solution! This is not working @Felippe

Comment: @TasdikRahman try to reinstall both LibreOffice and ttf-mscorefonts-installer. Via Synaptic is easier(mouse right button in the package's name > reinstall... ) maybe it will work.

Comment: It seems that LibreOffice has boycotted all of the core microsoft fonts. I'm wondering if there's any kind of workaround possible to at least get Times New Roman into LibreOffice. So odd that they would just block LibreOffice from being able to import those fonts entirely.